# How can I get feedback from helm-projectile-ag that it's still searching?

Tags: helm-projectile, ag

When I do a helm-projectile-ag search, there's nothing telling me if it's still searching, is there?

Is there any way to show what directories it's working with, sort of being verbose?;)